# how to scroll horizontally right on iterm terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, iterm

I want to scroll horizontally since my window size doesn't cover all the info I need.

What's the shortcut to do this?[image]

In the screenshot above, it would be useful to scroll right so I can see the extra info. Currently, I am resizing the terminal, but this takes time.

Comment: I think it's impossible for it to overflow horizontally anyway. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @theonlygusti done.

Comment: What program is that in your screenshot?

Comment: @theonlygusti fzf

Comment: @theonlygusti `zl` and `zh` wouldn't work; the yellow bar at the bottom there is a cursor

Comment: This is an fzf issue not a Terminal one. Try looking up how to disable fzf's horizontal scroll, or how to tweak it